# oracle sql how to get apart year and apart month from varchar

Tags: sql, oracle

I have varchar column name `Calc_code`, with for example this varchar '`100201`', first two characters are Year (`2010`), third and fourth are month (`02`) and the last two characters are not related with date so they are not important. How will I convert into date so that I can in select in where clause give something like this:

---

```
select *
from  table_a 
where Calc_code >= p_year_from || p_month_from 
 and  Calc_code <= p_year_to || p_month_to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the first 4 chars and you can get them with the function [`substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm):

```
select *
from  table_a 
where substr(Calc_code, 1, 4) >= p_year_from || p_month_from 
 and  substr(Calc_code, 1, 4) <= p_year_to || p_month_to
```

I assume that `p_year_from`, `p_month_from`, `p_year_to` and `p_month_to` are strings (since you concatenate them), padded with a `0` at the left if necessary.

Comment: If it is from `9901` to `0001` then this will not return any rows.

Comment: @MT0 saving the year in 2 digits only is problematic by itself, but since the OP  does not mention this it means that it does not pose any problem for the current requirement.

Comment: The OP mentions that the `Calc_code` uses 2-digit years so it is reasonable to assume that the other values are also 2-digit years. However, if they are 4-digit years then your code doesn't work as you would be comparing the substring `1002` from `Calc_code` with `'2010' || '02'`.

Comment: @MT0 True, but I guess the OP would mention the difference in the format.

Answer (score 1):

Need to take the first four digits into consideration and then we can convert it using `TO_DATE` as following:

```
select to_date(SUBSTR('100201',1,4),'YYMM') FROM DUAL;
```

Note that output will be the first date of the month as the date is not given in `TO_DATE` function

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_DATE` with the first 4 character substring of your value:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE( SUBSTR( calc_code, 1, 4 ), 'RRMM' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

So your assuming your `p_year_from`, etc values are numbers then the code would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_a 
WHERE  TO_DATE( SUBSTR( calc_code, 1, 4 ), 'RRMM' )
       BETWEEN TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( p_year_from, '00' ) || TO_CHAR( p_month_from, '00' ), 'RRMM' )
       AND     TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( p_year_to,   '00' ) || TO_CHAR( p_month_to,   '00' ), 'RRMM' )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   with YR_FROM as (select to_char(to_date(SUBSTR('100201',1,4),'YYMM'), 'YYYY-MM') FROM DUAL),--2010 Feb
          YR_TO as (select to_char(to_date(SUBSTR('100301',1,4),'YYMM'), 'YYYY-MM') FROM DUAL) --2010 March
    Select * from  table_a
    where to_char(CREATE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') between (select * from YR_FROM) and (select * from YR_TO);

    --Will give zero results
    with YR as (select to_char(to_date(SUBSTR('100201',1,4),'YYMM'), 'YYYY-MM') FROM DUAL)
    Select * from  table_a
    where to_char(CREATE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') >= (select * from YR)
      and to_char(CREATE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') <=(select * from YR);
```